# visual studio 2015: setup EF6 with oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create Entity framework 6 model for an Oracle Database.

Install `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework` from nuget

```
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/
```

Then install `Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015`:

```
http://download.oracle.com/otn/other/ole-oo4o/ODTforVS2015_121025.exe
```

Here is my app.config:

```
<configSections>
<section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client"
      type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
...
<entityFramework>
<providers>
<provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
        type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
```

...

However i got this error message when adding `ADO.NET Entity Data Model`:
[image]

Any idea pls?

Comment: Are you have installed ODAC ?If yes which version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install `ODAC (Oracle Data Access Components)`.It offers four components that simplify .NET development with the Oracle Database:

-Oracle Data Provider for .NET

-Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio

-Oracle Providers for ASP.NET

-.NET stored procedures

In `ODAC 12c Release 3` (12.1.0.2.1), Oracle includes Entity
Framework 6 Code First and Code First Migrations. Also you can use
`ODAC 12c Release 4` includes support for Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015, .NET Framework 4.6 and more.

[Oracle .NET Developer Center](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html)

If you have installed ODAC use `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`, add like reference to Your project.

Example path look like:

> C:\app{userName}\product{version
>   ODAC}\client_1\odp.net\bin{framework version}
>
> C:\app\mww\product\11.2.0\client_1\odp.net\bin\4

Comment: which version in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html?

Comment: Download and install latest version from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html

Comment: working -  have to install ODAC 32bit to get it in VS2015